# How do you access a function name not what the function returns in python?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, random

My question pertains specifically to the random module, in my code when i save a random number to a variable or within a list my function becomes a permanent number.

```
def d4(num=None):
    if num is None:
        num = random.randint(1, 4)
        return num


def d6(num=None):
    if num is None:
        num = random.randint(1, 6)
        return num 

(self explanatory for the rest of dice)

diceDict = {'d4': d4(), 'd6': d6(), 'd8': d8(), 'd10': d10(), 'd12': d12(), 'd20': d20()}
player1 = [d4(), d4()]
player2 = [d4(), d4()]

def getKey(die):
    for key, value in diceDict.items():
        if die == value:
            return key

print(f'P1 dice are: {getKey(player1[0])} and {getKey(player1[1])}')
        print(f'P2 dice are: {getKey(player2[0])} and {getKey(player2[1])}')
```

so what this is supposed to do is tell them what dice they have in their hand but what it does is... say the d8() in diceDict rolls a 2, then every time a dice rolls a 2 it says they have a d8. please help!

Comment: The `()` calls the function. To simply store a reference to a function, omit the `()`.

Comment: However, the point of functions is to make them as generalized as possible. Why not a `roll_die` function which accepts a number of sides so that you could do `roll_die(4)` or `roll_die(20)` to roll 1d4 or 1d20, etc?

Comment: Another question, what is the point of `if num is None` if you don't also do something when `num` isn't `None`?

Comment: Can you also explain what your intention is with storing a dictionary of dice rolls? Note that when you do `player1 = [d4(), d4()]` you are in fact, *rolling 2d4* and creating a list of two integers randomly chosen between 1 and 4. When you then attempt to access the dice dictionary with one of these values, you'll get a key error because the only keys in the dictionary are strings, not integers.

Comment: okay @ddejohn you answered my question with your first 3 comments and after you answered then that last one was obsolete. I was ignorant about leaving out the parenthesis (I'm still waaaaay just beginning so thank you so much for answering) your second comment was really what did it though! I have no idea why I didn't think of that but that's all that is, I'm just learning at home so I am ignorant of a lot of the common practices and am just figuring out functions and classes are still gibberish.

Comment: and the purpose of the third comment is so I could possibly store a truly random value in a variable because without that statement it wouldn't recreate a new number every time it was called. You have taught me so much with this and if you have a different way of recreating random numbers stored in a variable then i would totally be interested!